# Then I need to show that the topology induced in $A$ by $X$ coincides with the topology induced in $A$ by $Y$

Tags: general-topology

$X$ a topological space
$Y$ a subspace of $X$
$A$ a subspace of $Y$

That is $A \subset Y \subset X$

Then I need to show that the topology induced in $A$ by $X$ coincides with the topology induced in $A$ by $Y$

Be:

- $\tau_1$ the topology induced in $A$ by $Y$
- $\tau_2$ the topology induced in $A$ by $X$.
- $\tau_Y$ the $Y$ topology
- $\tau_X$ the $X$ topology
  We need to show that one is contained in the other.

Let $U \subset A$ tq $U \in \tau_1$. So there is an open $V \in \tau_Y$ tq $U = V \cap A$. But we know that if $V \in \tau_Y$ it means that there is $W$ in $\tau_X$ tq $V = W \cap Y$

So I have two equations:

$U = V \cap A$ (equation 1)

$V = W \cap Y$ (equation 2)

I need to show that $U$ is in $\tau_2$, meaning that $U = W \cap Y$.

If I substitute equation 2 for 1, I have:

$U = (W \cap Y) \cap A$.

Could someone help me finish?

Comment: Please do not make such significant edits to a question after it has been answered.  This has the potential to invalidate the given answer(s).

Comment: Sorry, I think I squeezed something wrong there.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A\subseteq Y,W\cap Y\cap A=W\cap A$. Thus $U=W\cap A\in\tau_2$.

---

For showing that $\tau_2\subseteq\tau_1$, proceed similarly.

> Let $U'\in\tau_2$. Then $U'=A\cap V'$ for some $V'\in\tau_X$. But $A\cap V'=A\cap\underbrace{Y\cap V'}_{M\in\tau_Y}\in\tau_1$.